# Python pickle can not save 3g size dictionary containing text and numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pickle

I have an increasing dictionary containing numpy arrar and text. When its get bigger ie `3g` in memory I cant save it with pickle. It is using to much memory. Normally its around `8g` program in top, when its saving its increasing to `15 g`.. My memory is `16g`. And the saving is unsuccessful.

How can I save such big dictionaries ? any idea ?

```
with open(file_name_pck, 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(enrol_full_dict, handle)
```

Comment: Is the numpy array the problem, or the text?

Comment: btw, what's the kind of data / problem you are dealing with? Depending on the use case, it might make more sense to use a standardized format. For instance: if your data is a dictionary of image data, you could write some wrappers that read / write your data to png files on disk, where the file names are associated with the dict keys. Or some database with blobs (sqlite is nice for that matter). It adds some overhead, but the data is likely to be stored in a more space-optimized manner, it will be more portable and you don't run the risk that if your big blob is corrupt, all your data is gone.

Comment: data is . text and 1024 x float32

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import cPickle as pickle
cPickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pickle
dict = { ' ': ,' ': }
filename = ' '
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(dict,outfile)
outfile.close()
```